# How would I solve this math problem on Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

$(3t^2 + 5t + a ) (4t^2 + bt - 2) = 12t^4 +26t^3 - 8t^2 - 16t + 6$

What is a + b?

The answer would be: 
$6=-2a$ 
$a=-3$ 
$-16t=(5t\cdot-2)+a\cdot bt\Longrightarrow-16t=-10t+(-3)bt\Longrightarrow b=2$ 
$a+b=-1$

Answer (score 8):

`SolveAlways[]` makes quick work of your problem:

```
SolveAlways[(3 t^2 + 5 t + a) (4 t^2 + b t - 2) == 12 t^4 + 26 t^3 - 8 t^2 - 16 t + 6, t]
   {{a -> -3, b -> 2}}
```

Answer (score 6):

One way could be

```
ClearAll[t,a,b}
z1 = CoefficientList[(3*t^2 + 5*t + a)*(4*t^2 + b*t - 2), t];
z2 = CoefficientList[12*t^4 + 26*t^3 - 8*t^2 - 16*t + 6, t];
eqs = Thread[z1 == z2];
Solve[eqs,{a,b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Reduce[ForAll[t, (3*t^2 + 5*t + a)*(4*t^2 + b*t - 2) == 12*t^4 + 26*t^3 - 8*t^2 - 16*t + 6], a]
```

> b == 2 && a == -3